# Android OpenGL colors of texture degradation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am using OpenGL for 2D graphics, loading texture from 32-bit PNG image and
when texture is drawn on the screen, colors look weird.
It looks like colors are not totally accurate, something like less than 8 bits 
are used for each channel.

On the image below on the LEFT is original output from device, on the RIGHT is original image.
You can see that gradient is not smooth in the rendered image.

[image: Problem]

Here is the same image with added contrast, so you can see better these artifacts.

[image: Problem with High Contrast]

Is this normal or not? What can I do about this?

Note: Rendered on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0

Comment: On SGS2 it happens so that GLSurfaceView selects RGB565 color mode by default. Setting this to RGB888 manually when initiating GLSurfaceView helps on my phone at least. Maybe it's the case with Galaxy Tab too?

Comment: Maybe... how can I set this mode?

Comment: GLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 8). Where last two values vary on your needs for depth & stencil buffers.

Comment: YES! That was the problem. You can write the answer and I will accept. It will be very helpful to others. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try setting RGB888 mode manually for GLSurfaceView:

```
GLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 8)
```

Where last two values vary on your needs for depth and stencil buffers. At least on SGS2 it's the case that the device selects RGB565 color mode by default causing some banding with colours.